# MS Access Query: how to sum between recurrence dates starting from a certain date period

Tags: sql, ms-access

OK,
the question is not clear:

I wish to sum/calculate trough query something monthly, but every month will start for example from the 20th to the 19 of the next month.

thanks for you help

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: OK, instead to group per month, I need to group per month but starting for example from the 20th to the 19 of the next month.

all the dates between
January 2020: from 20/12/2019 to 19/01/2020
February 2020: from 20/1/2019 to 19/02/2020

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract 19 days from the date and then extract the year and month:

```
select year(dateadd("d", -19, datecol)), month(dateadd("d", -19, datecol)),
       count(*)
from t
group by year(dateadd("d", -19, datecol)), month(dateadd("d", -19, datecol))
order by min(datecol);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's work as my request, only one remark,
the counting of the months start from the previous month:

15/07/2020 -> return 7, shall return 6.
So I edit and use your string as follow:

Month(DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("d",-19,[dateimport])),Month(DateAdd("d",-19,[dateimport]))+1,1))

could be correct? or is there something more faster?
My skill is obviously bad... ;)

Comment: You can add one month to the date, if you want reporting from that month.  For instance: `year(dateadd("m", 1, dateadd("d", -19, datecol)))`.